# how to verify a reboot occurs?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I want to reboot some instances using `ec2.reboot_instances([instanceId])` and 
that works fine but:

1. how to verify a reboot occurs? I thought `launch_time` will be changed but looks like all parameters remains the same.. I'd prefer to do this check without ssh or ping - is it possible? May be it's possible to use `instance.get_console_output()` somehow?
2. it's not clear from the docs if I should add some instance status check before trying to reboot. If instance is terminated request will be ignored, that's clear - but if is's stopped or pending - should I use something else instead (start)?

Comment: It's probably possible to parse the get_console_output() but there can be delays before that information is available to you.  I'm not aware of any data that is returned from EC2 (e.g. status or reason) that would help.  I think the solution below (ssh in and run uptime) is about as good as you can do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This shell command will give you how long the system has been booted:

```
ssh hostname uptime
```

To automate it you will want to add you ssh public key to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the host.

With boto it would probably be something like this (although I've not used boto):

```
s = boto.manage.cmdshell.SSHClient(hostname, uname='root')
s.run('uptime')
```

See the reference on the [boto manage module](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/manage.html)